Logo Design for Chinese Language & Usage Site
Well established Stack Exchange sites, like Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User and Programmers all have their own logo, and I think this helps give them more of an 'identity'.
Does anyone have any suggestions, concepts or ideas?

Why not do 漢 in a calligraphic style? 

I think one character is all we really need. More refinement can go into it to express it's own unique style. 

Simple, but I like it. The 'brush stroke' effect is a nice touch

Nice, maybe in a red-golden palette as most chinese signs

I almost used this character for the "sketchy beta" logo.. but decided not to show any bias :)

Now that I think of it, isn't this the Japanese version (kan)? I'm pretty sure the traditional chinese version has the vertical strokes of the grass top part united in a U form.

Yes, in Chinese, the top right is 廿.

The site will get its logo and design when it comes out of beta. And I am sure SE's designer Jin Yang will do a good job coming up with a design when the time comes.
I think improving the site with quality questions and answers and get more traffic in, so it will graduate sooner is the priority right now. None of the language & usage sites seem to be doing particularly well (except English).

That being said, I have only one request: Please don't make the site too red. I am sure Jin won't do that, but just in case...
I think a calligraphic style like Krazer suggests in his/her answer will do just fine.

I agree that promotion is important, but didn't see the harm in discussing other aspects

@Cocowalla Yeah, you are right. I just think this should be a little lower on the priority list.

yes, I agree with you

you like red? will do!

It may be a while until this site graduates. But I always appreciate it when the community starts the design discussion early, so when the time comes I'd have a list of ideas.

I just came across this online seal generator.
As a simple concept, what about selecting some text (i.e. 中文 as suggested by Mr Shiny and New), and using something like this generates? A few samples:




Ah yes, seals. Illegible script, Top-to-bottom, RTL word order. But, also, appropriate.

Yes, it's true that very few would be able to read the old Chinese script on the first 2, but I think they still represent a symbol that many people would associate with China.

+1 for first one

this is what I have in mind for final logo, with 漢.

Why not this one?

like @Krazer said, we only need one simple symbol.
That would do it, but you will have to resize it.

I'm going to suggest this because it's the most obvious thing to suggest:
中文
Just take those characters, print them in a nice font, and fit them into a square. Or, since Chinese characters are usually square anyway, any one of these:
Characters relating to China/Chinese people:
中
华
唐
汉
Characters relating to language:
字
文
话
语
言

In such case, I'd suggest only 中, since it's usually associated with China, or 中文.

@Alenanno: 华, 唐, and 汉 are all words used to describe China or Chinese people too, and are less cliche than 中.

I wouldn't say it's cliche. Among the meanings of 中, there's also "China", so it's not cliche, it's just its meaning.

@Alenanno: what I mean is, it gets used as a logo quite often, for obvious reasons. Our logo should be distinguishable from the multitude of other Chinese-language websites.

That is a good point. In that case, I agree with you.

唐茶's logo may be a very good lead. They deliver very well formatted chinese book as iOS app

@Alenanno: Should we be wary of associating it too much with China (as in the country)? - Main reason is, my impression is this SE is about the language, Chinese; many other countries other than China use the language. Also, would a logo with Simplified characters potentially deter new comers who are learning Traditional?

@pyko: My personal view on simplified characters is that you can't argue with a billion people who are all using simplified. Any student these days who is learning Mandarin needs to learn simplified at some point, and should not be too dismayed when a logo uses simplified. Anyway, they still won't be able to properly read most questions and answers in simplified.

@Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 - agree with you re learning simplified at some point (I was initially taught traditional and intend on learning to read/write traditional, but have started to learn to read simplified). What I mean is there are so many "Learn Chinese" sites which cater for simplified only - if the SE logo uses simplified, it may give a wrong impression (since this is a Chinese language site for both traditional and simplified)

I wasn't expecting this topic to be opened now, since it's very early. But nothing denies us from discussing about it. :D
When I think about China, something that often comes to my mind is the dragon. I think most people identify China with that. I'm not sure this can be applied to the language too, just giving an idea... :)
What about these too? Not a picture but a sketch/simplification of them would do the trick...

'dragon' is the first thing that came to my mind too, but maybe that has something to do with my profile picture :)

@Cocowalla eheh I noticed your gravatar, but "dragon" is pretty much screaming "chinese!" from each letter... :D
